# How to use variables from .env in Micronaut application.yml?

Tags: micronaut

I am very new to Micronaut and I just want to ask because I couldnt get any answers from the offical docs

I have a .env file on the root of my folder. Here's my .env

```
PORT=8081
```

I tried to access the PORT variable on my application.yml but it is not reading the variable from .env file. Here's my application.yml

```
micronaut:
    application:
        name: test-app
    server:
        port:${PORT}
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to tell to micronaut to use `.env` file if you want to use it.
Generally micronaut uses `application.yml` so you can configure your app with the following way:

Micronaut reads environment variables from the OS. Our `application.yml` would look like this:

```
micronaut:
    application:
        name: test-app
    server:
        port:${PORT:8000} # :8000 is a default value.
```

Now for example on linux start without env variable:

```
$ ./mvnw mn:run # start micronaut 
[main] INFO  io.micronaut.runtime.Micronaut - Startup completed in 1102ms. Server Running: http://localhost:8000
```

Start with env variable:

```
$ export PORT=8080
$ ./mvnw mn:run # start micronaut 
[main] INFO  io.micronaut.runtime.Micronaut - Startup completed in 1102ms. Server Running: http://localhost:8080
```

As you can see it will took the variable from your OS path.